# Understanding Matplotlib Inputs

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphics

I'm trying to understand how to use matplotlib's [surface_plots](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots). The documentation says that the values must be 2D arrays, but what exactly do these arrays represent?

That is, I can understand an X, Y, Z system, but these inputs would simply be 1D arrays, so what is the second dimension for?

I've looked at the examples, but the input data format is not obvious to me.

Comment: If you just had a 1D array for each X, Y, and Z you'd just have a line in 3D (each point being the corresponding elements from each vector). You need an x and y grid over which you have a z value to create a surface

Comment: Plotting points in 3-dimensions would only need 1D arrays, however `plot_surface` creates 3D polygons, it's not a scatter plot, so there needs to be a method for creating these polygons from the input data.  More specifically, `plot_surface` creates polygons with four vertices, `trisurf` creates polygons with three vertices.  As mentioned in the documentation, these are passed to `Poly3DCollection`.  The different dimensions of the input arrays determine how the polygons are constructed - they determine the vertices that define the polygons.

Comment: @Suever, You're right, now I understand. You need to have a way of determining how the surface is "connected".